# SQL Server to MySQL, which fork?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mariadb, percona

I have to migrate a SQL Server database to  MySQL but i have no idea which fork to use (MySQL, Percona or MariaDB).

We don't have so much experience with MySQL and we haven't used it for high production workload.

Asynchronous replication cross datacenter for disaster recovery failover is required.

The database is used for a read intensive application but we will use cache layers and we are more concerned about new user peak traffic with writes for registrations etc

Is there a fork that fits best our needs?

Comment: We migrated from SQL Server 2014 to MySQL 5.7.18. Everything works fine. No issues in the last three months at all.  Replication works like a charm.  Slave is located out of state yet updates are almost instantaneous.  Keep in mind, Stored Procedures and Views will require manual attention as they are not automatically converted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- MariaDB is the open source community driven version that has the  endorsement of all of the unaffiliated MySQL developers.
- MySQL is a trademark owned by Oracle and which has continued developed funded by Oracle. Some of this development is pretty awesome. I wouldn't discard it. I believe the Oracle developers are likely more skilled than the community working on MySQL.
- PostgreSQL is the best and most advanced open source database. Though it has nothing at all to do with MySQL, I highly suggest you use it instead. It's faster, more spec compliant, and better documented.

The Maria vs MySQL is a mess and all feature comparisons are pretty bad. So read them all! Good luck with it.

- MariaDB official comparison: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/

Comment: I add my opinion here. Me too suggesting Postgresql.